# Get True false result in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables (friends and users) and i want to get list of all users but there should be clear that whether that is my friend or not,my current id is "81"

```
Friends
id      user_id     friend_id 
32      81          169       
33      81          170
34      83          171
```

Users

```
id      first_name
81      byt          
169     abc               
170     def         
171     xyz
```

I tried with following code but i am getting only users who are in my friend list, i want all but with status/result that is this my friend or not

```
$this->db->select('friends.user_id,friends.friend_id,users.first_name,users.last_name,users.image');
$this->db->from('friends');
$this->db->join('users', 'users.id=friends.friend_id');
$this->db->where('friends.user_id', $add_data['user_id']);
```

Comment: So what is your question? What is going wrong? We need some more input or we cannot help you ;)

Comment: You table structure is a bit confusing. Is the friend_id linked to the user.id? And if not what is the friend_id?

Comment: @Paladin : my question is simple, i just want to get all records ( whether that is in my friend list/friend table or not, but i want to know friends status or you can say add column in result of my query True/False  )

Comment: @pr1nc3 : For registered users i have users table and if i add someone in my friend list then entry will save into friends table so now i want to get all users but i want to know who is my friend or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it all within MySQL, this is the query you have to run:

```
SELECT u.id, NOT ISNULL(f.friend_id) as is_friend
FROM users u LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT f.friend_id FROM friends f WHERE f.user_id = 81) f
ON u.id = f.friend_id
WHERE u.id != 81;
```

Basically, you join all users with the table of all friends of a specific `id`. Then you check whether the `friend_id` is `null` (due to the left join behavior).

See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a23c9/3) an example.

Comment: result is good but i want all record except 81 in list(result) because that is user

Comment: Just add a `WHERE` clause like the updated version of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('friends.user_id,friends.friend_id,users.first_name,users.last_name,users.image');
$this->db->from('friends');
$this->db->join('users', 'users.id=friends.friend_id');
```

If you want to get them all but know which ones are your friends then you need to handle that in php. Above query will retrieve all the info from both tables.

Now moving futher:

```
$result = $query->result_array();

foreach($result as $row){

    if($row['user_id'] == $add_data['user_id']){
        $friendsArray[] = $row['friend_id'];
    }
}
```

This will create a new array with your `friend_ids` that match your `user_id`. Basically the logic you tried to do in your where clause i did it in php since you wanted to retrieve all of them.

If you want to use the rest data that are not in your friendlist you can alway use an `else` statement inside the foreach loop.